# YouTube Video Not Appearing on Page

Tags: html, web, deployment

I am unable to get this (https://youtu.be/gnRxUDOJ-M0) youtube video to play in my browser even though I have another video that is working as intended.  I'm not seeing what I am missing?

https://thepowerhousemethod.org/nextsteps.html

**Working**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/gnRxUDOJ-M0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Not Working**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/X0wNGbjmU4w" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Looks like your site is not using the embed URL which is the one that should work.

Comment: great thank you been stuck on this for hour!

Answer (score 0):

Use the embed URL from Youtube and paste to .html page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).